# Getting a new variable with custom output and not a constructor location (name@xxxxx) - Java

Tags: java, class, methods, output

I've been trying to make a custom output from the constructor in Java, but it keeps giving me the location of it. The `return` does not work and throws up an error. The code is:

```
Public class Example {
public static int a, b;

Example(int inputForA, int inputForB){
   a = inputForA;
   b = inputForB;
   }
}
```

The output i want is a/b (a fraction, for example 3/2).
I tried a return command, but it does not work:

```
Public class Example {
public static int a, b;

Example(int inputForA, int inputForB){
   a = inputForA;
   b = inputForB;
   return a +"/"+ b; //i even tried making String Example(){...} in the beginning but it still does not work, throws an error
   }
}
```

The output i'm getting, when i am trying to print Example (3, 2)`System.out.println(Example(3, 2))` is `Example@4dd8dc3` and as mentioned i need `3/2`.

Is there a way to do it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example is a class, not a method. It's like a template for an object.

But you can put a method in that class that returns what you want.

Example.java

```
    package myPackage;

    public class Example 
    {
     public static int a, b;

     Example(int inputForA, int inputForB)
     {
       a = inputForA;
       b = inputForB;
     }
     float compute ()
     {
        return (float)a/(float)b;
     }
    }//_Example
```

Now we create an instance of Example and use this object in another class.

Main.java

```
    package myPackage;

    public class Main
    {
     public static void main(String []args)
     {
        Example exp = new Example (3, 2);
        System.out.println(exp.compute());

     }//_main
    }//_Main
```